# Find the number of zeros after decimal point in $0.2^{25}$

Tags: logarithms, decimal-expansion

> Find the number of zeroes immediately after decimal point in $(0.2)^{25}$,given that $\log 2=0.30101$

My attempt: I found the answer as $17.\dots$

Should we add $1$ as $17$ is the characteristic or leave it as 17?

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 3):

You've found that $0.2^{25} = 10^{-17.47\dots}$, so
$
   10^{-18} < 0.2^{25} < 10^{-17},
$
that is
$$
   \underbrace{0.0\dots 0}_\text{$18$ zéros}1 < 0.2^{25} <  \underbrace{0.0\dots 0}_\text{$17$ zéros}1,
$$
so we conclude that there are $17$ zéros after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$ \log_{10} 0.2^{25} = 25 \cdot \log_{10} \frac 2{10} = 25 \cdot (\log_{10} 2 - 1) \approx -17.4743 $$
That gives, by monotinicity of $x \mapsto 10^{x}$ that 
$$ 10^{-18} < 10^{-17.4743\ldots} = 0.2^{25} < 10^{-17}, $$
hence $0.2^{25}$ has 17 zeros after the decimal point, no need to add 1.

Answer (score 0):

let $(0.2)^{25}=x$

$\implies \log (0.2)^{25}=\log x $

$\implies 25\log (0.2)=\log x $

$\implies 25(\log 2-\log 10=\log x) $

$\implies 25(0.30101-1)=\log x $

$\implies \log x = -17.47475$

$\therefore$Characteristic=17=number of zeroes immediately after decimal point in $(0.2)^{25}$

**Note-**  "$characteristic+1$" gives total number of digits.