# Number of zeros between decimal and first significant digit

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can we determine number of zeros between decimal and first significant digit in $\big(\frac{1}{6}\big)^{200}$?

I can't develop any fruitful approach for this question. Could some provide some hint?

Comment: You need to use base $10$ logarithm. A number is between $10^{-n}$ and $10^{-n+1}$ if and only if its logarithm is between $-n$ and $-n+1$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: This http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454962/find-the-number-of-zeros-after-decimal-point-in-0-225 might help.

Comment: @Crostul Thank you for the hint. Could you post your comment as answer so that I could accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number $x$ satisfies
$$10^{-n} \le x \le 10^{-n+1}$$
if and only if $$-n \le \log_{10} x \le -n+1$$
Now, $$\log_{10} 6^{-200} = -200 \log_{10} 6 = -155.6... < -155$$
so that your number has $155$ zeroes after the point.